# Applying jQuery event handler to all elements of same type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, event-handling

I have what I hope will be a simple question. I am new to jQuery and JavaScript more generally.

I am trying to write a simple jQuery event handler that will highlight li's on my page when I mouse over them. I tried:

```
$( 'li' ).on('mouseover', function(evt) {
   $( evt.target ).effect( 'highlight', {}, 1000 ); 
});
```

and it does not work. It doesn't produce an error, but there is no result.

However, if I try something like:

```
$( document ).on('mouseover', function(evt) {
   $( evt.target ).effect( 'highlight', {}, 1000 ); 
});
```

I am able to highlight any DOM element I want by mousing over it.

I placed the event handler at the end of my js file, and with the second approach shown, even dynamically-generated DOM elements can be highlighted without problems. However, if I try to select a DOM element by tag or even by class, I am unable to produce any effect.

Comment: Change evt.target to this

Comment: For dynamic content use: `$(document).on('yourevent', 'yourelement', function(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delegating up to document like so since you're targeting dynamic content :

```
$( document ).on('mouseover', 'li', function(evt) {
  $( evt.target ).effect( 'highlight', {}, 1000 ); 
});
```

You might need read this [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: That did it! Thank you :)